# continuity of a metric d

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

from [Continuity of the Metric and Convergence Sequences](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109726/continuity-of-the-metric-and-convergence-sequences?rq=1), why $d^{-1}(V)$ is an open ball?

to be an open ball, I think it contains elements of $X$, not $X^{2}$. why is it?

Comment: It is an open *set*, not necessarily an open *ball*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, $d^{-1}(V)$ is a subset of $X^2$, and unless you define a metric on $X^2$ (which would be a function from $X^4 \to [0,\infty)$) it does not make sense to talk about $d^{-1}(V)$ being a ball.  What we can say is that $d^{-1}(V)$ is open in the product topology on $X^2$.

Comment: a metric $d$ on a set X  maps $X \times X\rightarrow [0,\infty)$

Comment: How can we show that $d^{-1}(V)$ is open? I tried to make a basis element, but it didn't work well..